# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error?

Tags: ios, xcode5, linker-errors

[image]I am getting this below error can any one suggest me how to rectify this error.
 Here is my error

```
 warning: ignoring file /Users/xyz/Downloads/CC3x/CC3x/libFTC_RELEASE.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/xyz/Downloads/CC3x/CC3x/libFTC_RELEASE.a (2 slices)ignoring file /Users/xyz/Downloads/CC3x/CC3x/libFTC_DEBUG.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/xyz/Downloads/CC3x/CC3x/libFTC_DEBUG.a (2 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FirstTimeConfig", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in CC3xUtility.o
  objc-class-ref in CC3xMainViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in CC3xMainViewController_iPad.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You are building your application for Simulator?

Comment: yes i am running it in simulator.

Comment: Compile your libFTC_RELEASE for simulator and build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you are trying to build your project and one of your valid architectures is i386 but you are including a library that doesn't have an i386 slice.

Comment: Since you are building for the simulator, you can avoid this error by changing your project build setting: build only active architechtures to yes

Comment: @DovD. i have this issue. i changed build settings, but it stil same error. how do i resolve this.

Comment: @akk: You may have multiple build settings for different libraries. Be sure to check each one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all it worked for me on device by setting active architectures to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Build settings -> enable bitcode : NO

and add the .a files from cc3000 project file to your project.

It worked for me